# Application.Context.User not filled on request without .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have the following setup:

- IIS 7.
- using the url rewrite module from UrlRewritingNet
- A custom IHttpModule which authenticates requests

In my sitemap file I have certain urls with roles defined. :

```
<siteMapNode url="~/directurl" roles="Clients">
<siteMapNode url="~/directurl.aspx" roles="Clients">
```

When i make a request for both:

```
if (Application.Context.User == null)
{
    /* This is where the first request ends */
}
else
{
    /* This is where the second request ends */
    /* This is where they both should be */
}
```

What do I need to do so the User is filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in IIS7. You need to add the below

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

read this blog

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast answer. Had a hard time googling for it :)

Comment: At first it seemed to work. Strange enough on the production server The Application.Context.User is still null and therefor the checks wont work. Is there any setting which might interfere with this?